# Multiple repetitions in a single rule

Tags: esper

I'm trying to express the rule "at least two `foo`s followed by two `bar`s within 2 seconds" in EPL. I've tried using both patterns and `match_recognize`, and I can't get the semantics I want. I've modified the `StockTick` example from the online EPL tool to illustrate what I'm doing.

I've tried the two patterns below:

```
select g[0].seq, g[1].seq, g[2].seq, g[3].seq, y[0].seq, y[1].seq from pattern [
     every ([2:] g=StockTick(symbol = 'GE') until timer:interval(2 sec)) -> not timer:interval(2 sec) and every [2] y=StockTick(symbol = 'YHOO')
];
```

and

```
select * from StockTick match_recognize (
   measures g[0].seq as g0_seq, g[1].seq as g1_seq, g[2].seq as g2_seq, g[3].seq as g3_seq, y[0].seq as y0_seq, y[1].seq as y1_seq
   pattern (g{2,} y{2})
   interval 2 sec
   define
       g as g.symbol = 'GE',
       y as y.symbol = 'YHOO'
);
```

for the following event definition:

```
create schema StockTick(seq int, symbol string);
```

on the following input:

```
StockTick={seq=1, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=2, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=3, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=4, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=5, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=6, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=7, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=8, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=9, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=10, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=11, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=12, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=13, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=14, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=15, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=16, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=17, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=18, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=19, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=20, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=21, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=22, symbol='YHOO'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=23, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=24, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=25, symbol='GE'}
t=t.plus(200 msec)
StockTick={seq=26, symbol='GE'}
```

and got the following output:

```
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:02.400
Statement: Stmt-2
Insert
Stmt-2-output={g[0].seq=1, g[1].seq=2, g[2].seq=3, g[3].seq=4, y[0].seq=12, y[1].seq=13}
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:03.000
Statement: Stmt-3
Insert
Stmt-3-output={g0_sec=6, g1_sec=7, g2_sec=8, g3_seq=(null), y0_seq=9, y1_seq=10}
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:03.800
Statement: Stmt-2
Insert
Stmt-2-output={g[0].seq=1, g[1].seq=2, g[2].seq=3, g[3].seq=4, y[0].seq=14, y[1].seq=20}
```

I understand with with the first EPL statement, the `until timer:interval(2 sec)` does not match the logic I actually intended, but I'm not sure how else to express it.

I have tried attaching windows (`#time(2 sec)`) to the patterns without the output changing.

I am looking to get matches with the following sequence numbers:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10)
(2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10)
etc.
```

such that the rule is evaluated for each 2 second window, and I get maximally long sequences of `g` in each of these windows.

Answer (score 0):

The "interval" in match-recognize has a different meaning. What you want is this:

```
select * from StockTick#time(2 sec) match_recognize...
```

The doc link is http://espertech.com/esper/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#match-recognize-datawindow

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've come to realize that one aspect of `match_recognize` that precludes it from doing what I need is that `g{2,}` will only match _consecutive_ events, whereas I don't want that restriction. Which I guess leaves me with patterns. Do you have a solution for patterns?